# Using DeamonPortOptions to fix DKIM signing with genericstable masquerading

Tags: debian, sendmail, masquerade, opendkim

I'm sending mails from my debian server with sendmail. I want to be able to send mail with multiple domains using masquerading with genericstable. I am signing the mails with OpenDKIM but because OpenDKIM signs the mail before masquerading happens the keys don't match.

OpenDKIM addresses this problem on their [README page](http://www.opendkim.org/README)

> Due to the way the milter protocol is incorporated into the MTA, opendkim
>   sees the headers before they are modified as required by those two features.
>   This means the DKIM signature is generated based on the headers originally
>   injected by the mail client and not on the headers which are actually sent
>   out by the MTA.  As a result, the verifying agent at the receiver's side
>   will be unable to verify the signature as the signed data and the received
>   data don't match.
>
> The suggested solutions to this problem are:
>
> (1) Send mail with the headers already written as needed, obviating the
>       need for these features (or just turn them off).
>
> (2) Have two MTAs set up, either on separate boxes or on the same box.
>       The first MTA should do all of the rewriting (i.e. use these two
>       features) and the second one should use opendkim to add the signature
>       and do no rewriting at all.
>
> (3) Have multiple DaemonPortOptions lines in your configuration file.  The
>       first daemon port (port 25) does the header rewriting and then routes
>       the message to the second port; the latter does no rewriting but does the
>       signing and then sends the message on its way.

I want to use the 3rd solutions to fix the problem but I can't figure out how to start. For reasons I do not want to use the first solution.

My current DeamonPortOptions in my sendmail.mc file are

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea')dnl
```

Is it possible to set my sendmail to use 1 port for masquerading and another for adding DKIM and sending like the README suggests?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need help on?  The configuration file in question is generally `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`.  What `DaemonPortOptions` entry do you currently have there?

Comment: @MikeB I updated my question for you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the Masquerading features and settings in my `submit.mc`/`submit.cf` configurations.  That way the local mail program (MSP) changes the From: header before it is sent to the DKIM milter by the MTA.

I used the same `MASQUERADE_AS` and `MASQUERADE_DOMAIN` lines as I have in `sendmail.mc`